# Getting error while downloading excel in Mozilla

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting error while I am opening an excel file in Mozilla. It works fine in IE. I have the below code:

```
String file="abc.xls";
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition:", "attachment; filename="+file); 
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
            response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Please help.

Comment: Instead of getting a popup to open or save a file, the page opens with funky characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Firefox profile and edit "Plugin MIME type" information in order to handle this type of files.

Check these pages:

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/set-how-firefox-handles-different-file-types

Comment: But I cannot tell user to change profile settings if they are opening it in firefox. This needs to be handled through code.

Comment: try changing the MIME type from "application/vnd.ms-excel" to "application/x-excel" or "application/excel"